# How to use Object.values on array in req.body in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, vue.js

I'm creating app in Vue.js and Node.js. I am sending the array to the backend, where the keys are the id numbers:

[image]

When I use this at frontend:

```
console.log(Object.keys(item)[2])
console.log(Object.values(item)[2])
```

It display the correct values:

[image]

When I use the same method in backend:

```
router.post('/post', (req, res) => {
  let data = req.body;
console.log(Object.keys(data)[2])
console.log(Object.values(data)[2])
});
```

I get undefined value.

How to display this data correctly in backend?

Edit:

trans.service.js:

```
    static async addTrans(item) {
        console.log(item)
        console.log(Object.keys(item)[2])
        console.log(Object.values(item)[2])
        const res = await api.post('translation/post', item);
        try {
            return res.data;
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    }
```

item value from console log:

```
[
60a2381cbcecaa11346bd7c2: ""
60a23815bcecaa11346bd7c1: "nnn"
609e5e1e6f19442da0fe5b99: "bbbddd"
609e5e166f19442da0fe5b98: ""
]
```

Comment: can you console log your req.body first and check what that logs?

Comment: @Mayur afrer use `console.log(req.body)` I get just this: `[]`

Comment: so can you verify if you're sending the data correctly as part of the body to the post request

Comment: The first image of data from this question is the console.log of what is sending in request

Comment: can you copy the snippet in trans.service.js file, I think there's some issue there only while doing the post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the frontend I declared this item as arrays and it was supposed to be an object. I changed the arrays to an object and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `express` for the server, then to read JSON data you need to add

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

form the npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Json encoding are not defaults of express.

Also try checking that, you are passing correct `content-type` header from browser to node, it should be `'application/json'`, you can check this in network tab of browser.

Comment: I use express and instead of body parser I use: `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` and `app.use(express.json())`. Is a body parser also necessary in this case?

Comment: if you are using `express.json()` then  `bodyParser.json()` is not needed, check in network tab, if the data is getting sent from the network call?, I hope it's not a GET request, req.body works with POST etc

Comment: The first image of data from this question is the console.log of what is sending in request in frontend, but afrer use `console.log(req.body)` in backend I get just this: `[]`

Comment: i think you might need to dig into `const res = await api.post('translation/post', item);` the reason is, it might be stringifying the array to empty.
can you check network tab, while sending the request, this will validate if the problem is with frontend or backend, console.log() might nt help in UI, check network logs